# How do I set a Magento page's template to the 2-column layout?

Tags: magento-1.7, php

Using the Magento layout XML, how do I set the page to use the 2-column layout template?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You will need to add this to the layout xml. Locate your `local.xml` in your theme layout folder (or create it if it doesn't exist) and set the template per page. For example for the default category pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   [...]
   <catalog_category_default translate="label">
     <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
   </catalog_category_default>
   [...]
</layout>
```

For CMS pages this can be done from the backend.

Comment: hi sander, I had tryied this, but not applying..

Comment: You should probably check if you've used the right template file and it's not overwritten

Answer (score 5):

you do it  via admin and can assign the template you want to  home page and other page like categories and cms pages.
in `design tab` set the value of `Page Layout`. which design you want to set on that product.

Comment: wow you're right. I completely forgot about setting templates for categories from the backend. Basicly only custom extensions need a setTemplate action from the layout XML