# How do I change Magento's default page template for the product description page?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, layout, template

How can I change Magento's default page template for product detailed/ single/ description page?

By default, it is always pulling this template,

```
 frontend\MY_WEBSITENAME\default\template\page/2columns-right.phtml
```

What about if I want it to pull this layout instead?

```
2columns-left.phtml
```

so the path should be,

```
frontend\MY_WEBSITENAME\default\template\page/2columns-left.phtml
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

local.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout>
    <default>
       <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
       <remove name="tags_popular"/>
       <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
    </default>

    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
     <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
   </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

**EDIT 2:**

`catalog.xml`,

change,

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>    </action>
</reference>
```

to

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been asked before several times, I think [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/how-to-set-the-two-column-layout-in-my-magento-site/) might help you.

It comes down to adding the `<setTemplate>` tag to the root of the page in the layout xml

It should look something like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: thanks. I had tried it but it does not work. please see my edit above.

Comment: In what file did you do this? Could you maybe update your question with some XML snippets and file names?

Comment: I too have updated :) I think it's because of the page tag

Comment: see my edit above. the change should be made in `catalog.xml`. thanks :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, for the page you're trying to change you should use `catalog_product_view`. The only place you need to do this is the `local.xml`. This layout XML is always loaded last.

Comment: thanks so much for the update. it works it that way too. good to know there are many ways to achieve it. thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: I got this working but I don't know how to add blocks to the left side. Can you add how to the answer?

Comment: You can read more on layout on http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates In your case use `<reference name="left">` to target the left column

Comment: I tried that: http://jsfiddle.net/janw_oostendorp/XTCB2/2/ it doesn't work

Comment: you've used `<reference name="right">`, but since you're using the template `2columns-left.phtml` use `<reference name="left">`

Comment: See my edit. But  I've figurted it out. I didn't have any related products to show. Adding subscribe block works

Comment: try adding it in the `local.xml` to make sure it's not overwritten and indeed, make sure you have related products